# Yii2 Copy table from one db to another db

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

In yii2 I have to copy the whole table from one DB to another DB

and for that I used bellow code but its throing error:

```
$dbName = "db1";
$table = "demotable";
$liveDbName = "db2";
$command3 = $connection->createCommand('CREATE TABLE `'.$dbName.'.'.$table.'` SELECT * FROM `'.$liveDbName.'.'.$table.'`');
$command3->execute();
```

but getting error like:

```
Database Exception – yii\db\Exception
SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'db1.db2.demotable' doesnt exist
The SQL being executed was: CREATE TABLE `db1.demotable` SELECT * FROM `db2.demotable`

Error Info: Array
(
    [0] => 42S02
    [1] => 1146
    [2] => Table 'db1.db2.demotable' doesnt exist
)
```

Comment: What is your `$connection`? This is where underlying database is defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to specify a database with a table, there should be two different string divided by a dot.`` `database`.`table` ``.

In your code
`` `'.$dbName.'.'.$table.'` `` will return the united string `` `db1.demotable` ``. So SQL are trying to find a table with the name "db1.demotable". The same problem with the second table.

Try to use this code:

```
$dbName = "db1";
$table = "demotable";
$liveDbName = "db2";
$command3 = $connection->createCommand("CREATE TABLE `$dbName`.`$table` SELECT * FROM `$liveDbName`.`$table`");
$command3->execute();
```